# Этимология слова «зловред»

Tags: этимология

Существует такое слово, как «зловред» в значении «вредоносная программа» (источник — [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5:%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3#.D0.97)).

Откуда в нём взялся корень *-вред*? Разве он не является тавтологией в свете наличия корня *зло-*?

Да и слово «добровред» мне неизвестно (единичный пример в виде каламбурного имени [выдуманного персонажа](http://godville.net/gods/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4) в рассчёт не берём).

Comment: _Arhad: Да и слово «добровред» мне неизвестно..._ === Да, такого слова нет, как нет и слова "добровредный". А вот "зловредный" существует (см. http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4)%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x). И от него легко образовать с аналогичным значением и слово "зловред".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вред —  это порча, ущерб, а слово "злой" —  многозначное (11 значений в словаре, из них только первое значение противоположно слову "добрый": 1. Наполненный чувством вражды, недоброжелательности (противоп.: добрый).).

Но зловред (если есть такое слово) —  это скорее не злой, а **злоумышленный вред**.

ЗЛОУМЫШЛЕННЫЙ,  Совершённый со злым **намерением;** преступный.

Comment: в данном случае зловред - это субъект, причиняющий вред. Это не "вред, совершенный намеренно"

Comment: Ну тогда это субъект, причиняющий вред намеренно.

Comment: Да нет, это скорее плеоназм, если уж вы такой знаток стилистики. "Зловредный" похож на "своими собственными глазами".

Answer (score 3):

Это слово из сетевого жаргона. Вот что пишет [Викиреальность](http://wikireality.ru/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4):

*Зловред — буквальный перевод термина «**malware**», ныне довольно распространённый в среде защиты от вирусов.*

*Описание*

*Зловред — программа, наносящая ущерб компьютеру или хранящейся на ней информации: вирус, троянская программа и т. п.*

*Самые распространённые зловреды: троянские программы, делающие из компьютеров элементы ботнета; заставляющие пользователя вводить номер телефона и отправлять дорогие SMS; ворующие информацию.*

*Название применяется на сайтах, посвящённых борьбе в вирусами, в новостях: «Новый зловред под Android перехватывает тайны пользователей».*

От себя добавлю, что malware - это **специально разработанное** вредоносное программное средство, оно приносит намеренный (**зло**намеренный) вред. Значит **зловред** - приносяший **зло**намеренный **вред**.