# Этимология слова "зловредный"

Tags: этимология

Отвечая на [вопрос об этимологии слова "зловред"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431973/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4) (из сетевого жаргона), участники предположили что **зловред** - это программа, приносящая **зло**намеренный **вред**. А как объяснить этимологию слова "зловредный"? Согласно словарям, зловредный - очень вредный (нет указания на злонамеренность). Возможно, "зловредный" произошло от "зело вредный"?

Answer (score 2):

Ребят, не ЗЕЛО, а ЗЪЛО, что совсем другой коленкор.

[**ЗЛО**](http://enc-dic.com/semenov/Zlo-817.html)

> Старославянское – зъло (беда, грех).
>
> На Руси слово начало использоваться рано – с XI в. В древнерусский
>   язык слово проникло из старославянского и довольно быстро получило
>   широкое распространение.

А дальше - сложение основ: зл(о) + вред (сложение с суффиксацией).

[**ВРЕД**](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-2194.htm)

> заимств. из цслав., см. *ве́ред*.

**[ВЕРЕД](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-1766.htm)**

> «рана, нарыв, гнойник», ст.-слав. врѣдъ (др.-греч. βλάβη, μώλωψ),
>   русск. вред (из церк.-слав.).

*Зловредный - раненный грехом...*

Можно немножко подсмотреть в этимологический словарь Шанского, хотя само искомое слово "зловредный" учёный в него не включил (думаю, по причине "прозрачности"):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не от "зело". Буквы просто так пропадать не могут. )

Проще всего предположить, что это обычный плеоназм.

Answer (score 1):

В первой составляющей отмечена превосходная и крайняя степень смысла слова.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Зловредный*, стало быть, — это губительный, разрушительный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Того же значения (что и *Зло*) наречие *Зело*, зило — сильно, весьма, крайне.